# Simple Ruby loop through array does not iterate completely

Tags: ruby, arrays

So I thought I understood this, but I'm not getting the output I expected, so obviously I don't understand it.

In Ruby (2.0.0)

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.each do |e|
    a.delete(e)
end
a = [2,4]
```

It doesn't seem to be looping through each item in the array. However, when I simply output the item, it loops through each item. There's some mechanism of a.delete(e) that is affecting the iteration.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.each do |e|
    puts e
end
=> 1
=> 2
=> 3
=> 4
```

Ultimately, I want to put a conditional into the loop, such as:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.each do |e|
    if e < 3
        a.delete(e)
    end
end
```

How can I get this loop it iterate through each item and delete it? Thank you!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Clarified the question.

Comment: In future, consider holding off for awhile before choosing an answer.  A quick choice (here, a mere 15 minutes after posting!) may discourage other, possibly better, answers, and, imo, is not respectful to those still preparing answers.

Comment: Thanks for the beta. I've unselected the answer and will give it some time before re-accepting.

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with with @sawa's answer, which I think is quite good, and got a vote from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.each do |e|
  a.delete(e)
end
a # => [2, 4]
```

The first iteration was at index `0` with `e` being `1`. That being deleted, `a` becomes `[2,3,4]` and the next iteration is at index `1`, with `e` being `3`. That being deleted,  `a` becomes `[2,4]`. The next iteration would be at index `2`, but since `a` is not that long anymore, it stops, returning `a`'s value as `[2, 4]`.

In order to iterate through each item and delete it, given that there is no duplicate, a common way is to iterate backwards.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.reverse_each do |e|
  a.delete(e)
end
a # => []

a = [1,2,3,4]
a.reverse_each do |e|
  if e < 3
    a.delete(e)
  end
end
a # => [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

DO NOT mutate a collection when you iterate over it, <del>unless you know what you are doing</del>.

For your *ultimate* purpose,

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.reject!{|e| e < 3 }
```

Comment: I would even say not even if you know what you're doing. It wouldn't make for very readable code, especially when ruby has lovely methods like `reject!` and `select!`, like you mentioned.

Comment: @PaulRichter Yes, I agree with you. That's bug prone and rely heavily on the implementation details.

Comment: I think JRuby will throw a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` in this case. At least with `Array` and `Hash` which are actually backed by Java collections in JRuby.